# Error when trying to use Destructuring as function parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to learn how to use destructuring as a parameter.
I have the following code

```
  const states = {
    selected: '-selected',
    excluded: '-excluded',
    notSelected: '-notSelected'
  }


  function showSelected({selected}) {
    alert(selected);
  }

 showSelected(); //Cannot destructure property 'selected' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
```

The problem is that when I call the function I get this error:

'Cannot destructure property 'selected' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.'

but the value of selected variable is there, if i do something like console.log(states.selected), I just get the right value

what I'm missing here?

JSfiddle with my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/db97z3uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing parameter:

```
showSelected(states);
```

So, without parameter, you're destructuring with `undefined`.

If you expect it to be with the variable defined outside of the function scope would do that, you will need to do like:

```
  function showSelected({selected} = states) {
    alert(selected);
  }
  showSelected()
```

Now, without parameter, it will result the default selected value from states.

Answer (score 0):

We you call the `showSelected()` and sending no parameter, you are sending `undefined` as paramater and getting `selected` from `undefined` create the error.
You can call like this:

```js
showSelected({})
```